# Updating state with different values does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, dynamic, react-hooks

I created simple sandbox for easier understanding of my problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fermat-egww0?file=/src/App.js

**Issue description:**

I have 2 products and each of that product has 2 different color variants. The application is very simple e-commerce thing, so in the bottom I have summary of chosen color variant products.

It works all fine, but both of the products are having the same color, and my expected behaviour is that they each should have different color that has been picked.

I think the issue is that products are sharing one state and I am not sure what is the solution to that, since data are dynamic.

Comment: When you have complex state logic, it's best to use a reducer. Otherwise, managing the state could become VERY convoluted. https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/basic-reducer-structure

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @JoelHager, I never used redux, but I'll try to read about it.

Comment: You don't need redux to implement a simple reducer. I don't have redux and I use a reducer. I wish I could show code without posting an 'answer' per se, because I think it would help you see how they're formed.

Comment: @JoelHager thank you for explanation. You can use my sandbox link and create simple example there if you want. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the problem is that your components are sharing the `state` set by `setSelectedData` and `setSelectedColor`.

You need to make your components don't use the same `state`, or use it in a way it makes sense, for example using an array of objects, where each item  represents the different `state` of the items being represented by your components.

Here's a working example using parts of your data: https://codesandbox.io/s/n68iw